# Insert unique records into table based on calculation of other table column MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, bulkinsert

I have two tables(**ProductionDetails**, **Production**), I need to populate Production based on calculated values of the ProductionDetails. ProductionDetails has the number of buckets gathered, Production needs to be populated with BINS. For example if I have **100** buckets, and I divide those by 30 that equals **3.33** bins. Now I need to create 3 BINS.

```
select Round( sum(ep.Buckets)/30),ep.lot,ep.crewid 
from On_EmpProdDetails ep
group by ep.buckets,  ep.lot,ep.crewid
```

Results in

| Bins | Lot | Crew |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 556790186SOCC1 | SOCC1 |

Now I want to insert 3 unique rows into the Production Table
BinID is auto increment

| BinID | LOT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 556790186SOCC1 |
| 2 | 556790186SOCC1 |
| 3 | 556790186SOCC1 |

Comment: Provide the source, not a result of intermediate query only, in the form of CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Provide final data state for this source data. Specify precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate the rows:

```
insert into production (lot)
    with recursive cte as (
          select Round( sum(ep.Buckets)/30) as num_bins, ep.lot, ep.crewid, 1 as bin 
          from On_EmpProdDetails ep
          group by ep.buckets,  ep.lot,ep.crewid 
          union all
          select num_bins, lot, crewid, bin + 1
          from cte
          where bin < num_bins
         )
    select lot
    from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c8b0af03b29782ed0ecef510abf4a68) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your reply 
I gave it a shot and I'm getting an error
insert into On_CrewProduction (Lot)
    with recursive cte as (
          select Round( sum(ep.Buckets)/30) as num_bins,ep.crew,ep.Date,  ep.lot, ep.crewid, 1 as bin 
          from On_EmpProdDetails ep
          group by ep.buckets,  ep.lot,ep.crewid 
          union all
          select num_bins, lot, crewid, bin + 1
          from cte
          where bin < num_bins
         )
    select lot
    from cte;

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'recursive cte as (
          select Round( sum(ep.Buckets)/30) as num_bins,ep.c' at line 2

Comment: Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.23 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: I added a db<>fiddle.  However, this code requires MySQL 8+, which has been in release for over three years.